# Is there a way to get the current time in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to inject the time of an nginx server into an HTTP header.

I am able to add to an HTTP header, like so:

```
proxy_set_header HELLO-WORLD 'something';
```

But now, I want to be able to inject the time into an HTTP header, something that looks like this:

```
proxy_set_header THE-TIME $time_var;
```

Or something like that.

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use variables from SSI modulе: $date_gmt and $date_local

```
proxy_set_header THE-TIME $date_gmt;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#variables

Comment: Hi, I want to know how to format the date here. I want it formatted as year-month like `2016-12`

Comment: I was able to format datetime in an nginx response: `return 200 '<!--#config timefmt="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" --><!--#echo var="DATE_GMT" -->\n';` But no idea how to use SSI for header value. The variable $date_gmt is provided by the nginx ssi module (it's a normal nginx variable, so it can be used in a header value), but apparently cannot be formatted using `<!--#config timefmt=...`.

Comment: @Messa, I solved this issue like this:
`<!--# config timefmt="%Y-%m-%d" -->`
`<!--# set var="date" value="$date_local" -->`
`<!--# include virtual="/ssi.php?date=$date&and-other-parameters-here" -->`

In nginx config, you can get the variable through `$arg_date`

Answer (score 5):

`$time_iso8601` is both machine- & human-friendly.