# Get a string of current time since epoch (seconds) in nginx

Tags: nginx

In nginx configuration file, what is the best way to get a variable containing string representation of current time in seconds since epoch? Conceptually I want something like this:

```
$timestamp = <unix_time>;
add_header Time $timestamp;
```

As requested by a moderator, this is not a duplication of

[Is there a way to get the current time in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789194/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-current-time-in-nginx)

as variables `$date_gmt and $date_local` do not provide seconds-since-epoch format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the current time in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789194/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-current-time-in-nginx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the functionality was added to this module:

https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module

Sought line would be:

`set_formatted_gmt_time $unix_time_str "%s";`

Answer (score 5):

As per [the docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_msec), it's in the `$msec` variable.

Answer (score 0):

While one use case is setting a header, the question is generic, so here are some more usage examples for the [`$msec`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_msec) timestamp:

### Logging:

The nginx `log_format` directive can use `$msec`:

```
  log_format timed '[$time_local]  '
                    '"$request" $status  $body_bytes_sent B '
                    'at $msec ' ;
```

Results in logs of the format:

```
- [01/Nov/2023:18:52:05 +0000]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200  870 B at 1698864725.928
```

### URL that returns the timestamp:

My use case was requesting the server timestamp via http. This solution requires the use of the `echo` module (was available by default in my installation.)

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;
```

The location block inside my server block was as follows:

```
location /ts {
  default_type 'text/plain';
  echo -n "$msec";
}
```

Fetching this route simply returns the timestamp string:

```
> curl https://myserver.com/ts
1698866215.554
```