# nginx - get hour and weekday

Tags: nginx, time

I need to obtain hour and weekday into variables to be used in config file.

Hour can be obtain from `$time_iso8601` using a regexp map, but it's overkill (like I said: based on regexp).

For weekday I cannot find any solution (not even a bad one).

Is there a better solution to implement those in nginx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't call that one an overkill, especially if you have a [PCRE JIT](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#pcre_jit) enabled nginx build (requires support from the system PCRE library). To get the weekday (as well as an hour too) you can use the `$date_gmt`/`$date_local` variables from the [`ngx_http_ssi_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) in conjunction with the `map` block. I don't find a way to return the time string using custom [`strftime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) format, it seems that the mentioned `timefmt` parameter is supported only in SSI commands used within the `<!-- ... -->` blocks of post-processed response body. You should be aware that the `strftime()` result for the `%a`/`%A`/`%b`/`%B`/`%c` format modifiers can be locale-dependent on some systems/nginx builds. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789194/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-current-time-in-nginx) SO thread, depending on how are you going to use those values it may be useful for you too.

I doubt there is a better solution with the vanilla nginx, but if you are not limited to built-in modules only, there is a [`set-misc-nginx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module) which has the [`set_formatted_gmt_time`](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module#set_formatted_gmt_time) / [`set_formatted_local_time`](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module#set_formatted_local_time) directives where you can specify an exact `strftime()` format (`%u`/`%w`/`%H`). This module is also a part of the [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/) bundle.